# How to add time when I add a job in my Todo App?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to add time when I add a job. (I use ReactNative)
(like time when you send a message in Facebook)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `new Date().toISOString()` to get the current date time in ISO format when you add a job and store it in your database or wherever you store your data.

and then use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to display the date or time according to your desired format

Comment: FYI there are native methods to format a date, eg. [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: @Apolo Yeah i know that but it's not as flexible as moment js